# Why does $\text{res}_\xi\left( \frac{H(z)}{P(z)} \right) = \frac{H(\xi)}{P'(\xi)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am reading some notes on residues which claims that
$$
\text{res}_\xi\left( \frac{H(z)}{P(z)} \right) = \frac{H(\xi)}{P'(\xi)}
$$
if $\xi$ is a simple pole and $H,P$ are polynomials. I'm not sure why this is true, but I tried writing out the derivative of $P(z)$ and it seems to be pointing in the right direction:
$$
P(z) = (z-\xi)Q(z)
$$
and
$$
P'(z) = Q(z) + (z-\xi)Q'(z)
$$
notice that $Q(\xi), Q'(\xi) \neq 0$. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You may have neglected stating some conditions on the analyticity of $H$ and $P$, e.g., $H$ being analytic and $P$ having a zero. Of course, the textbook may just specify only the fraction $\frac HP$ has a simple pole. The analysis will be different. You have to specify the complete premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a simple pole, the residue is
$$\lim_{z\to\xi}(z-\xi)\frac{H(z)}{P(z)}
=\lim_{z\to\xi}H(z)\times
\left(\lim_{z\to\xi}\frac{P(z)-P(\xi)}{z-\xi}
\right)^{-1}=H(\xi)P'(\xi)^{-1}.$$

Comment: Why does this limit definition hold? I have not seen this before.

Comment: It is the **definition** of the derivative.

Comment: No, I mean of the residue.

Comment: Oh, is this because if you take the Laurent series of $H/P$ and then multiply by $(z-\zeta)$ you are shifting the indices by one, hence you want to find the zeroth term?

Comment: You are making several assumptions that are not specified by the OP. See my comment below his question.

Comment: @Hans Done. They are polynomial functions

Comment: It is still missing conditions. $P(z)$ must have a simple zero at $z=\xi$ which is not stated. Having settled all these, you have to use the property of polynomial. The steps per se in the answer is unjustified, so the derivation per se is incorrect. I do not understand why you accept the answer as it is.