# Why does $\text{res}_\xi\left( \frac{H(z)P'(z)}{P(z)} \right) = mH(\xi)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Given polynomials $H,P$ such that $P$ vanishes at $\xi$ with order $m$, how can I show
$$
\text{res}_\xi\left( \frac{H(z)P'(z)}{P(z)} \right) = mH(\xi)?
$$
Going off my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382583/why-does-textres-xi-left-frachzpz-right-frach-xip-xi), I think I should write the equation as
$$
H(z) \cdot (z-\xi)\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}
$$
then, taking the limit $z \to \xi$ I should get
$$
\lim_{z\to \xi}\frac{P'(Z)(z-\xi)}{P(z)} = m
$$
Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}=\frac m{z-\xi}+Q(z)$$
where $Q$ is analytic near $\xi$, so that
$$\lim_{z\to\xi}(z-\xi)\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}=m$$
etc.